# ngx-socket-io not working {} has no property msg

Tags: sockets, angular7

Trying to just do the ngx-socket-io tutorial and I keep getting the error Property msg doesn't exist on type {}.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

I have everything installed right and have everything I need in the AppModule.ts and I have map and socket imported as well.

My ChatService.ts

```
constructor(private socket: Socket){}

sendMessage(msg: String){
    this.socket.emit("message", msg);
}

getMessage() {
   return this.socket.fromEvent("message").pipe(map(data => data.msg));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .fromEvent method is a generic that will take a type specifier... try either providing a specific type or defining data as `any`.  For example:

Somewhere define:

```
export IMyDataType {
    msg: string;
}
```

Then call the fromEvent with a type specified:

```
getMessage() {
   return this.socket.fromEvent<IMyDataType>("message").pipe(map(data => data.msg));
}
```

Or assume that data is `any`:

```
getMessage() {
   return this.socket.fromEvent("message").pipe(map((data: any) => data.msg));
}
```